# Is there any functioning AMM on devnet?

Tags: devnet, swap

I want to swap my devnet SOL for some other devnet token, for example USDC. Is there any functioning AMM on Devnet where this is possible? Preferably one that automatically handles the wrapping on the SOL in the background before swapping?